# Compile from source in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm looking to specifiy that i want that one of my depedencies needs to be compiled from source in package.json to npm.
I searched in google but I didn't found any way to do this.
Is it simply possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps like compiling would be executed during either a "prepublish" or "install" script hook: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

And npm recommends using gyp to create build scripts necessary for packages: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp